# How do you find which list values in a dictionary has the most elements in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So say there are list values in the second values of a dictionary: Dict[int, Tuple[int, List[int]]]. A list can have different elements, but how do I know which list has the most elements? I know you'll need to loop through the keys of the dictionary so that looks like:
for k in dictionary:

but then what do you do? I know I will also need a variable to count the number of elements for each list, so that looks something like: n = len(dictionary[k][1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `max` function, and use the `key` argument to extract the value interesting you for the maximum:

```
max(dict.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1][1]))
```